# Angular 2 get Input element value

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

how to  get html element value using ionic 2

Below my html code

```
 <div class="messagesholder" *ngFor="let chat of chatval | orderby:'[date]'" >
   <div *ngIf="chat.sender == currentuser || chat.receiver == currentuser">
    <div  *ngIf="chat.date" style="text-align: center;" >
           <p style="font-size:9px;" id="amount" #amount>{{chat.date | amDateFormat:'LL'}}</p>
           <input #myname [ngModel]="range" (ngModelChange)="saverange($event)"/>
         <input #myname type="text" value={{chat.date}}>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="message" *ngIf="chat.sender == currentuser || chat.receiver == currentuser" [ngClass]="{'me': currentuser == chat.sender}">
          <div class='image' *ngIf="chat.path" >
            <img *ngIf="chat.path" [src]="chat.path"/><br>
            <span *ngIf="chat.path_text">{{chat.path_text}}</span>
            <span style="font-size:9px;">{{chat.date | amDateFormat:'hh:mmA'}}</span>
          </div> 
           <div *ngIf="chat.message_text">
           <span>{{chat.message_text}}</span>
           <span style="font-size:9px;">{{chat.date | amDateFormat:'hh:mmA'}}</span>
           </div>
    </div>
```

Below my ts file

```
import { Component,Inject,ViewChild,ElementRef,AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';

export class ChatPage implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('myname') input:ElementRef; 
  constructor(public modalCtrl: ModalController,public navCtrl: NavController) {}
   ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.input.nativeElement.value);
    }
  }
```

Same date values are repeated.I want same date values are not repeated.

Because I will check two variable.

so I need chat.date value.because i binded the value of input.But i cannot get the value of input element.

i am getting this error

Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

How to fix this issue.or any other way to find slutions.

Thanks

Comment: why do you want to use ElementRef, you can simply use ngModel

Comment: Thanks.How can I consoled the ngModel value in constructor.

Comment: are you assigning any value when u initialize the component for the first time

Comment: No.I does not assign any value in component.

Comment: Then you will get undefined

Comment: k. i not used input tag using this <p style="font-size:9px;" id="amount" #amount>user name</p> Now how can i access this element

Comment: you should be seeing these in google.

Comment: I tried to many way but i have no idea. : (

Comment: update your post with the exact one you are look for instead of lengthy conversations

Comment: are you sure all the if conditions in your code is true?

Comment: Ya.Its true.I have all date values.Pls refer this imgur.com/dpnLSSv I need same date values are does not show.How to fix it

Answer (score 33):

I created a plnkr link: https://plnkr.co/edit/49TEP8lB4lNJEKsy3IDq?p=preview

It works for me so probably you may want to create your own plnkr so ppl can help

```
export class ApiDemoApp{
  root = ApiDemoPage;
  @ViewChild('myname') input:ElementRef; 
  constructor() {
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(this.input.nativeElement.value);
  }
}
```

Comment: .Thanks for ur reply.Ya.I implement my component.But still getting same error

Comment: Man, I have no idea, can you post everything about your component, I created a plunker and it works! Check out my answer for the link

Comment: implements AfterViewInit is just a Typescript construct which gets removed on transpilation to javascript..It is used to make sure you have implemented the correct lifecycle hook.. that really doesnt make a difference in this case

Comment: any other way to get input element value. I tried another way console.log(< HTMLInputElement > document.getElementById('amount').value); Its consoled the value of null.

Comment: The way you are doing is the correct way so there must be something else in your code causing it.

Comment: Why you need to get input value while you can get it by `chat.date` variable

Comment: And you are having 2 `myname` variables

Comment: Could this input field be fed into a `merge` pipe ? I'm trying at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52916861/have-an-observable-on-a-string

Comment: Could this input field be fed into a `merge` pipe ? I'm trying at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52916861/have-an-observable-on-a-string

Answer (score 9):

Use this code

```
@ViewChild('myname') input:any; 

ngAfterViewInit() {
 console.log(this.input.nativeElement.value) ;      
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.I use this code. i am getting following error  Cannot read property 'changes' of undefined

Comment: I think Mubashir meant to write `this.input.changes..`

Comment: I use also this.input.changes.Still get the same error

Comment: remove type 'hidden' with 'text' in input tag

Comment: Still i get this same error  Cannot read property 'changes' of undefined.otherwise i used <p style="font-size:9px;" id="amount" #amount>User name</p> How can i access this value.any other way to get input element value.Kindly help me.

Comment: may be *ngIf is causing problem in your code. have you tried it on simple input tag without inside ngIf ?

Comment: Now i remove check the condition of *ngIf="chat.date".still get same err

Answer (score 4):

If you using Directive
Try this way:

```
private el: HTMLInputElement;
constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef) {
    this.el = this._elementRef.nativeElement;
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.el.value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `input` element depends on the `*ngIf` condtion.

```
<div *ngIf="chat.sender == currentuser || chat.receiver == currentuser">
    <div *ngIf="chat.date" style="text-align: center;">
        <input #myname [ngModel]="range" (ngModelChange)="saverange($event)" />
        <input #myname type="text" value={{chat.date}} />
    </div>
</div>
```

`ngIf` directly manipulates the DOM. If the value is false your html element along with the outer div container gets removed from the DOM. Check [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html#!#ngIf)
This is why your `ViewChild` is undefined. You will need to check for the same conditions in your component or reconsider the logic where you are accessing the element in your component.
Try this:

```
ngAfterContentInit() {
    console.log(this.input.nativeElement.value);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.But.I have chat.date values are same.Pls refer this http://imgur.com/dpnLSSv I need same date values are does not show.How to fix it.

Comment: Try https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/AfterContentInit-class.html `ngAfterContentInit` lifecycle hook

Comment: Still.I am get this same error msg.But all if conditions are true.i have no idea.How to fix same date values are does not show.

Comment: No.does not wrk without ngIf.still get the same err.native element is undefined.

Comment: have you tried injecting elementRef in the constructor and `this.elementRef.getElementById("id_of_input")`?

Comment: I am getting this err this.element.getElementById is not a function

Comment: this.elementRef.nativeElement.getElementById("id").. sry

Comment: Still get this err this.element.nativeElement.getElementById is not a function

Comment: after you injected elementRef in the constructor?

Comment: Ya i inject constructor(@Inject(ElementRef) e: any) and assigned  this.element=e; after consoled console.log(this.element.nativeElement.getElementById("myname"))

Comment: Why i cannot get this input element value ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [ngModel](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/NgModel-directive.html).

On the basis of your code I made a small change to use ngModal. see [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24187081/).

```js
import { Component,Inject,ViewChild,ElementRef,AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';

export class ChatPage implements AfterViewInit {
  myname: string;
  constructor(public modalCtrl: ModalController,public navCtrl: NavController) {}
   ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.myname);
    }
  }
```

```html
<input [(ngModel)]="myname" type="hidden" value="John Doe">
```

Comment: .I used this.consoled  the value of this.myname is undefined .

Comment: You need to initialize the variable myname with your default value.

In you case I think default value is 'John Doe'. So use this

**myname: string = 'John Doe';**

Comment: k.But i dont need any initialize value and assing input tag. acutally i change my tag <p style="font-size:9px;" id="amount" #amount>{{chat.date | amDateFormat:'LL'}}</p> chat.date value binded to input tag.then how can i get this value

Comment: Use **chat.date** as **ngModal**

Comment: Pls refer this imgur.com/dpnLSSv I need same date values are does not show.How to fix it.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please specify your question. Use example if needed.

Comment: It worked for me. But it is `ngModel`, not `ngModal`. Anyway, this seems to be the preferred way to do it, and not using `ElementRef` as other answers seem to suggest

Answer (score 0):

If anyone interested how to check if nativeElement has empty data inside then use `textContent` property.

Suppose we have following HTML output from `nativeElement.outerHTML`:

```
<div _ngcontent-c8="" checkifelementempty="" class="some-class">
  <div _ngcontent-c8="">
     <b><i>&nbsp;a</i></b>
  </div>
</div>
```

To check if above HTML has empty text use this:
`!nativeElement.textContent.trim()`