# How to have the `searchTerm` input field being observed for its value change?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have two observables that work fine:

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

ngOnInit() {
  ...
  merge(this.sort.sortChange, this.paginator.page)
  .pipe(
    startWith({}),
    switchMap(() => {
      return this.getUsers(this.sort.active, this.sort.direction, this.paginator.pageIndex);
    }),
    map(userApi => {
```

This allows for the `getUsers` service method to be called when the sorting or the pagination is updated.

Now, I'd like to also have this service method being called when a search term is typed in:

```
@ViewChild(String) searchTerm: string;
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

ngOnInit() {
  ...
  merge(this.searchTerm.length, this.sort.sortChange, this.paginator.page)
  .pipe(
    startWith({}),
    switchMap(() => {
      return this.getUsers(this.searchTerm, this.sort.active, this.sort.direction, this.paginator.pageIndex);
    }),
    map(userApi => {
```

With the following template markup:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput #searchTerm (keyup)="search($event.target.value)" placeholder="User name" autocomplete="off">
</mat-form-field>
```

But the service method is then never called, not even at page load time.

My idea is to have the searchTerm an observable, and have this observable being observed by the `merge` method. This way I only have one method call to the `getUsers` service method.

I also tried this statement (without the `.length`) but it did not change anything:

```
merge(this.searchTerm, this.sort.sortChange, this.paginator.page)
```

UPDATE: I'm now trying something along this line:

```
@ViewChild('searchTerm') searchTerm: ElementRef;

merge(this.searchTerm.nativeElement.changes, this.sort.sortChange, this.paginator.page)
```

The `search` event handler does update fine the `searchTerm` member variable:

```
  search(searchTerm: string) {
    this.searchTerm.nativeElement.value = searchTerm.trim().toLowerCase();

    if (this.paginator) {
      this.paginator.firstPage();
    }
  }
```

I suppose I can get the value of the input field element to call the service method:

```
return this.getUsers(this.searchTerm.nativeElement.value, this.sort.active, this.sort.direction, this.paginator.pageIndex);
```

But the `merge` is not fireing if it includes the `this.searchTerm.nativeElement.changes` as in:

```
merge(this.searchTerm.nativeElement.changes, this.sort.sortChange, this.paginator.page)
```

How to have the `searchTerm` input field being observed for its value change ?

Comment: what is `this.searchTerm.length`? Please post all the relevant code

Comment: That's all the code there is. Indeed the .length is undefined.

Comment: @Stephane Why not use the `(ngModelChange)` or `(change)` bindings instead?

Comment: I added the template markup and you can see I make use of a `keyup` in there. I'm not sure that's the way to go. The whole point of my issue is to have all the events being observed by the same block of code, thus having only one call to the service method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally could solve the issue, using an `EventEmitter` object:

```
@Input() searchTerm: string;
@Output() searchTermEvent = new EventEmitter<{ value: string }>();

merge(this.searchTermEvent, this.sort.sortChange, this.paginator.page)
  .pipe(
    startWith({}),
    switchMap(() => {
      this.isLoadingResults = true;
      return this.getUsers(this.searchTerm, this.sort.active, this.sort.direction, this.paginator.pageIndex);
    }),
```

The event is emitted with the handler:

```
search(searchTerm: string) {
  this.searchTerm = searchTerm;
  this.searchTermEvent.emit({
    value: this.searchTerm
  });

  if (this.paginator) {
    this.paginator.firstPage();
  }
}
```

The `getUsers` service method is fired up on each input character.

Maybe there is a better alternative, but this works fine for now.